# Mac does not handle multiple Bluetooth peripherals properly

Tags: macos, mac, audio, mouse, bluetooth

I have a mysterious problem with Bluetooth peripherals on my Mac machine (MacBook Pro 2021 running Sonoma 14.2.1 (23C71)).

I (usually) connect three devices via Bluetooth:

1. Apple Magic Keyboard
2. [HP Bluetooth Mouse X4000b](https://www.amazon.co.uk/HP-94379XR-X4000b-Bluetooth-Mouse/dp/B009MMPBL0)
3. [Poly V8200 Headsets](https://www.poly.com/us/en/products/headsets/voyager/voyager-8200-uc)

After starting the machine the and connect the three devices, as soon as something is played through the headset (e.g., if I play music via Spotify or on YouTube, or even a system notification sound gets played), the mouse gets disconnected and reconnected arbitrarily (which is often perceived as annoying frozen pointers).

However, if I go to Bluetooth settings, ask the Mac to "forget" the headset, and pair it back, all three devices work stably.  Yet, as soon as either the headset or the mouse is disconnected and reconnected (e.g., if I turn one off when I take a break), the issue re-appears and I need to repeat the annoying "forget-and-pair" procedure.

More interestingly, if I only connect two of the three devices (even if those two are the headset and the mouse, i.e., I disconnect the keyboard), I do not have any problems.

I suspect this is due to some physical layer interference.  I.e., for some reason when all three devices are connected the [FHSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-hopping_spread_spectrum) protocols in both the mouse and the headset follow the same frequency sequence (hence their signals interfere).  But somehow when the headset is forgotten and reconnected this gets corrected.

Unfortunately I do not have much experience with Mac and Bluetooth to test the hypothesis or find a solution.  Has anyone had a similar issue?